# Problems searching for minPossibleKey for each binary tree node

Tags: c, binary-search-tree

What I'm trying to do is to, with a provided binary tree, calculate the lowest possible value for each node's key while still keeping the tree structure intact. Hence, from what I understand, the keys should be converted to 0,1,2,3,4 etc.

Example:

original tree connections

```
7 -- 5
7 -- 15
5 -- 2
15 -- 10
15 -- 21
10 -- 9
10 -- 13
```

intended connections:

```
2 -- 1
2 -- 6
1 -- 0
6 -- 4
6 -- 7
4 -- 3
4 -- 5
```

The code's aim is to print the min value for each key together with the key. The tree does not need to be changed itself.

The complete code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct TreeNode {
    int key;
    struct TreeNode* lChild;
    struct TreeNode* rChild;
} node;

// the following is test code
node *createTree(int key) {

    node *root = malloc(sizeof(node));

    root->key = key;
    root->lChild = NULL;
    root->rChild = NULL;

    return(root);

}

void insert(node *root, int key) {

    if (root->key == -1)
        root->key = key;

    else if (key < root->key) {

        if (root->lChild != NULL)
            insert(root->lChild, key);

        else {
            root->lChild = malloc(sizeof(node));
            root->lChild->key = key;
            root->lChild->lChild = NULL;
            root->lChild->rChild = NULL;
        }
    }

    else if (key > root->key) {

        if (root->rChild != NULL)
            insert(root->rChild, key);

        else {
            root->rChild = malloc(sizeof(node));
            root->rChild->key = key;
            root->rChild->lChild = NULL;
            root->rChild->rChild = NULL;
        }
    }

}

void printNode(node *root) {

    if (root->lChild != NULL) {

        printf("%d -- %d\n", root->key, root->lChild->key);

        if (root->rChild != NULL)
            printf("%d -- %d\n", root->key, root->rChild->key);

        printNode(root->lChild);
    }

    if (root->rChild != NULL) {

        if (root->lChild == NULL)
            printf("%d -- %d\n", root->key, root->rChild->key);

        printNode(root->rChild);
    }
}

void printTree(node *root) {

    printf("graph g {\n");

    printNode(root);

    printf("}\n");

}
//test code ends here

node *treeMin(node *root) {

    if (root->lChild != NULL)
        root = treeMin(root->lChild);

    return root;
}

node *treeSearch(node *root, int key) {

    if (root == NULL && root->key != key) {

        if (key < root->key)
            return treeSearch(root->lChild, key);

        else
            return treeSearch(root->rChild, key);
    }
}

node* succAbove(node* root, node* x) {

    node* succ;
    succ = NULL;

    while (root != x) {

        if (x->key < root->key) {
            succ = root;
            root = root->lChild;
        }


        else if (x->key > root->key)
            root = root->rChild;
    }

    return succ;
}

node *treeSucc(node *root) {

    if (root->rChild != NULL)
        return treeMin(root->rChild);

    node *parent = succAbove(root, treeMin(root));

    while (parent != NULL && root == parent->rChild) {

        root = parent;
        parent = succAbove(root, parent);
    }

    return parent;
}

void printMinKey(int key, int minPosKey) {
    printf("%d - %d\n", key, minPosKey);
}

int minKey(node *root, int count) {

    // as long as the parent node exists
    if (treeSucc(root) != NULL) {
        printMinKey(treeSucc(root)->key, ++count);
        minKey(treeSucc(root), count);
    }

}

void test() {

    node *root1 = createTree(-1);

    insert(root1, 7);
    insert(root1, 5);
    insert(root1, 15);
    insert(root1, 2);
    insert(root1, 10);
    insert(root1, 21);
    insert(root1, 9);
    insert(root1, 13);
    printTree(root1);

    printMinKey(treeMin(root1)->key, 0);

    minKey(root1, 0);

}

int main() {
    test();
}
```

The output is:

```
graph g {
7 -- 5
7 -- 15
5 -- 2
15 -- 10
15 -- 21
10 -- 9
10 -- 13
}
2 - 0
9 - 1

Process returned 0 (0x0)   execution time : 0.260 s
Press any key to continue.
```

The way I built this code is from various excerpts and material I have from class. I'm not actually sure I connected them all correctly. Specifically the `succAbove()`calls in `treeSucc()` I'm pretty much convinced are wrong but I'm not sure what to use instead.

The idea of `treeSearch()`, `succAbove()`etc. is, as far as I understand, that it doesn't require a parent-pointer to be added to the original struct.

The thought with the `count`in `minKey()`is that it would allow for me to easily get the minPossibleKey since it is increased in every recursion of `minKey()` and `treeSucc()`points to the successor which is the next lowest value. I'm not at all sure that my thought process there is correct though.

The parts marked as test code are not required in the exercise but are intended to help me see whether the other code works.

The intended output would be:

```
2 - 0
5 - 1
7 - 2
9 - 3
10 - 4
13 - 5
15 - 6
21 - 7
```

Comment: Can you tell me what the output you are expecting to get, if all was working well.

Comment: Ah, sorry, of course. I'll add it to the OP.

Comment: So, you objective is essentially sort a binary tree into a list based off key value? If so, you could recursively build that array, or simply dump all the Nodes into an array, and then sort it with whatever algorithm you choice.

Comment: That's true and I hadn't actually looked at it like that. The thing is, though, that the exercise is designed to go with a certain set of slides that contain the algorithms I implemented in my code above (although again, I'm not sure I did so successfully).